# Using vuex on Laravel 8 with Inertia Stack

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuex, inertiajs

I'm learning how to use Vuex, and I'm trying to use it on a Laravel 8 with Inertia Stack, i'm using vue 3.

Store/index.js

```
import { Store } from 'vuex'


export const store = new Store({
    state () {
        return {
            count:0
        }
    },
    mutations:{
        INCREMENT(state){
            state.count++
        },
        DECREMENT(state){
            state.count--
        }
    }
})
```

And here's my app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');

import { createApp, h } from 'vue';
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3';
import { InertiaProgress } from '@inertiajs/progress';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import { store } from './Store'

const appName = window.document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0]?.innerText || 'Laravel';

createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: (name) => require(`./Pages/${name}.vue`),
    setup({ el, app, props, plugin }) {

        return createApp({ render: () => h(app, props),store })
            .use(plugin)
            .use(Vuex)
            .mixin({ methods: {
                route,
             }
            })
            .mount(el);
    },
});

InertiaProgress.init({ color: '#4B5563' });
```

But I always end up with a console error:

```
app.js:106250 Uncaught Error: [vuex] must call Vue.use(Vuex) before creating a store instance.
```

I've also tried:

```
.use(store)
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I'll appreciate if someone can point me what i'm missing or what I'm doing wrong

Comment: In your **app.js** file remove `import { store } from './Store'` because you are not using it in this current file and try again.

Comment: Leave `import { store } from './Store'` in and add `use(store)` (instead of `Vuex`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem too with vuex 3.x.x
I did this and it worked:

```
npm uninstall --save vuex
```

Then i reinstalled it :
`npm install --save vuex@next`     (vuex 4.x.x) 
In app.js I used `.use(store)`. 
And I don't know if it change anything but in store/index.js I exported as `export default new Store({...})`

Comment: Thank you very much Cordellito, this did solve the issue for me. I can now learn how to use vuex.

Answer (score 1):

**Store/index.js**

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import { createStore } from 'vuex';

const store = createStore({
        state: {
            count:0
        },
        mutations:{
            INCREMENT(state){
                state.count++
            },
            DECREMENT(state){
                state.count--
            }
        }
    })

export default store
```

**And here's my app.js**

```
require('./bootstrap');

import { createApp, h } from 'vue';
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3';
import { InertiaProgress } from '@inertiajs/progress';
import store from '@/store/index';


const appName = window.document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0]?.innerText || 'Laravel';

createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: (name) => require(`./Pages/${name}.vue`),
    setup({ el, app, props, plugin }) {

        return createApp({ render: () => h(app, props),store })
            .use(plugin)
            .use(store)
            .mixin({ methods: {
                route,
             }
            })
            .mount(el);
    },
});

InertiaProgress.init({ color: '#4B5563' });
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).